# Do multiple opengl applications or contexts stall each other? Best practices? Driver dependent?

Tags: opengl

One of the themes in opengl is not stalling the pipeline.  If you have multiple applications running, does the system handle each frame of them at a time, or is the rendering interleaved drastically reducing overall performance?

Is the behavior similar for multiple windows each with their own dedicated non-shared (or shared) context?

For an application with multiple windows, is is recommended to do a frame in each window at a time or is it ok for each context to have a render thread that isn't synchronized with each other?

Multiple GPUs could interesting, I'm not sure how the behavior works dragging rendering apps onto another GPUs screen.

Comment: There's no generally applicable answer to that question. Runtime behaviour is completely up to each individual implementation and even different versions of the same family of implementations (e.g. there has been a major change in RT behaviour of NVidia drivers around the introduction of the G80 GPUs).

Comment: @datenwolf That sounds like one should do some basic synchronization just in case for a single GPU.  I believe the synchronization is desired, but I could be wrong if perhaps the drivers are able to interleave things more efficiently than could be done one at a time.  It sounds application dependent.  A slick system might be able to test a few frames here and there using a different method and switch to the best performing method automatically as it changes.

Comment: As a general rule: Don't try to outsmart the drivers! Large parts of current OpenGL drivers consists of tons of heuristics to determine which scheduling strategy to use. One of the major reasons for the creation of Vulkan was, that apart from these heuristics there is no way to actually "select" which codepath to use in the drivers. Hitting the fast codepath almost always boils down to (at least): Don't do c̶l̶e̶v̶e̶r̶ stupid things.

Comment: Stalling the pipeline is not the same as *starving* the pipeline. Stalling means, that one inserts commands into the queue that force the system to join asynchronous paths of operations (which means that slots in the pipeline that could do work are prevented from doing so) just to complete that operation. As it happens, threaded rendering synchronization (if done wrong) will pretty effectively stall the pipeline.

Comment: Not stalling the pipeline essentially boils down to not use anything that requires some form of hard synchronization, but allows for "soft" asynchronous execution. For example a `glReadPixels` or `glCopyTexImage` can be pretty devastating, because it potentially forces the pipeline to complete a picture before it can continue. However if done right rendering to a texture using a FBO and making sure that the generated image is used only much later gives ample opportunity to keep the GPU busy inbetween.